# NodeJS Serial with Arduino

Tags: node.js, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to read data from Arduino via NodeJS.I am getting these errors:

```
**/home/cihangir/Documents/Workspaces/Node JS/Arduino_RFID/index.js:10
    parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\r\n")
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'readline' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/cihangir/Documents/Workspaces/Node JS/Arduino_RFID/index.js:10:31)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
**
```

## The node.js serial communication code:

## index.js

```
var serialport =`require('serialport')` ;
var portName = '/dev/ttyUSB0';
var sp = new serialport.SerialPort(portName, {
    baudRate: 9600,
    dataBits: 8,
    parity: 'none',
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl: false,
    parser: serialport.parsers.readline("\r\n")
});

sp.on('data', function(input) {
    console.log(input);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try losing the backticks around the 'serialport' require.

Comment: DEPRECATION: Please use `require('serialport')` instead of `require('serialport').SerialPort`
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Error: No such file or directory, cannot open /dev/ttyUSB0

Comment: thanks that worked :)                                                                                   var serialport =require('serialport');